# Can CarrierWave upload to Amazon S3 but serve through CloudFront?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, amazon-cloudfront

I'm working on a small rails site which allows some users to upload images and others to see them. I started using CarrierWave with S3 as the storage medium and everything worked great but then I wanted to experiment with using CouldFront. I first added a `distribution` to my S3 bucket and then changed the CarrierWave configuration I was using to this:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage = :fog
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                                         # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],                       # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],                   # required
    :region                 => 'eu-west-1',
  }
  config.asset_host = 'http://static.my-domain.com/some-folder'
  config.fog_public     = true                                   # optional, defaults to    true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

I should mention that `http://static.my-domain.com` is a CNAME entry pointing to a CloudFront endpoint  (`some-id.cloudfront.net`). The result is that the pictures are shown correctly, URLs look like this: `http://static.my-domain.com/some-folder/uploads/gallery_image/attachment/161/large_image.jpg` but whenever I try to upload a photo or for that matter get the size of the uploaded attachment I get the following exception:

```
Excon::Errors::MovedPermanently: Expected(200) <=> Actual(301 Moved Permanently)
  response => #<Excon::Response:0x007f61fc3d1548 @data={:body=>"", 
  :headers=>{"x-amz-request-id"=>"some-id", "x-amz-id-2"=>"some-id", 
  "Content-Type"=>"application/xml", "Transfer-Encoding"=>"chunked", 
  "Date"=>"Mon, 31 Mar 2014 21:16:45 GMT", "Connection"=>"close", "Server"=>"AmazonS3"}, 
  :status=>301, :remote_ip=>"some-ip"}, @body="", @headers={"x-amz-request-id"=>"some-id", 
  "x-amz-id-2"=>"some-id", "Content-Type"=>"application/xml", 
  "Transfer-Encoding"=>"chunked", "Date"=>"Mon, 31 Mar 2014 21:16:45 GMT", 
  "Connection"=>"close", "Server"=>"AmazonS3"}, @status=301, @remote_ip="some-ip"
```

Just to add some more info, I tried the following:

- removing the region entry
- using the CloudFront URL directly instead of the CNAME
- specifying the Amazon endpoint (`https://s3-eu-west1.amazonaws.com`)

but all of them had no effect.

Is there something I'm missing or is it that CarrierWave does not support this at this time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to the question is YES. The reason why it didn't work with my configuration is that I was missing the `fog_directory` entry. When I added my `asset_host`, I removed `fog_directory` since the CDN urls being generated where malformed. I later found out that this was due to having `fog_public` set to false. After getting the proper CDN urls, I forgot to add `fog_directory` back since I could see my images and thought everything was fine. Anyway the correct configuration is:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage = :fog
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                                         # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],                       # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],                   # required
    :region                 => 'eu-west-1'
  }

  config.fog_directory  = '-bucket-name-/-some-folder-'
  config.asset_host = 'https://static.my-domain.com/-some-folder-'
  config.fog_public     = true                                   # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

Comment: I am using the same configuration just without the cname for cdn. While uploading photo, in form action it shows up the cdn url because of which the upload fails. Can you help me for it?

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `:asset_host` in your Uploader like so:

```
class ScreenshotUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :fog 

  # Configure uploads to be stored in a public Cloud Files container
  def fog_directory
    'my_public_container'
  end

  # Configure uploads to be delivered over Rackspace CDN
  def asset_host
   "c000000.cdn.rackspacecloud.com"
  end
end
```

Inspired from https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Store-private-public-uploads-in-different-Cloud-Files-Containers-with-Fog